# Reading from a Excel Cell

Tags: excel, epplus

I am using [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) package to read from an .xlsx file. I need to read a TimeSpan object from a cell. 
The excel cell would contain a data in "hh:mm" format, for example: "09:00" or "18:30" without the quotation marks.

Here is my code:

```
string myString = workSheet.Cells[1,1].Value.ToString();
double d = double.Parse(myString);
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(d);
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);
```

for "09:00" or "08:30" data in excel file myString contains "0.375", or "0.354166666666667" respectively and ts can be calculated as expected.
But for "10:00" in excel file myString contains
"30/12/1899 10:00:00 AM" and the parsing of the double value fails hence ts cannot be calculated.

I am not sure why this is happening inconsistently . How can I consistently read a double value from an excel cell (more precisely a cell with a General format)? Please help.

Here is my simplified code (After the suggestion from  Siddharth Rout):

```
string myString = workSheet.Cells[1,1].Text.ToString();
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(myString);
```

So far it is working with various values.

Comment: A Shot in the dark : `?Format("09:00", "0.000000000000")` in VBA gives `0.375000000000` Similarly `?Format("08:30", "0.000000000000")` gives `0.354166666667` and `?Format("10:00", "0.000000000000")` gives `0.416666666667` So if we can get the "10:00" from the cell then we are in the game... Well See what does `string myString = workSheet.Cells[1,1].Text.ToString();` give you?

Comment: Excellent! string myString = workSheet.Cells[1,1].Text.ToString(); is giving the desired double value. need to check thoroughly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SiddharthRout should add this as the answer and Choudhury should accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my simplified code (After the suggestion from Siddharth Rout):

```
string myString = String.Format("{0}", workSheet.Cells[1,1].Text);
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(myString);
```

So far it is working with various values.

Comment: ToString() is typically not "best" practice, given that it will thrown an exception for null values. 

String.Format("{0}", worksheet.Cells[1,1].Text) is the proper syntax here.