# C# - How to get excel cell value and its format

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

Is it possible to get Excel cell value with its format(Number, date or general) with C#? I am using EPPLUS library right now but it does not have this option.

Comment: I think is answer your question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983399/reading-from-a-excel-cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is basically try to cast cell value to certain type. EPPLUS handles conversion for you. If conversion succeeded, value was properly formatted for a specified type. I do not know if there is better way, but i used this in my code:

```
var file= new FileInfo(path);

using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

    var cell = sheet.Cells["A1"];

    if(cell.Value is DateTime)
    {
          //logic for datetime
    }
    else if(cell.Value is double)
    {
          //you get the point :)
    }        
}
```